# Crear vista personalizada para Error Exception en Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera crear vistas de errores personalizadas, tengo creadas las ubicaciones en Handler.php

pero cuando tengo un error: ERROR_EXCEPTION no se redirige a la vista de error:500

tendria que crear alguno vista extra para este error?

mi codigo es:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 500) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }
    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 503) {
        return response()->view('errors.503', [], 503);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);

}
```

Comment: Intenta debugear el estatus de tu exception y asi podras saber porque no esta devolviendote lo que esperabas. Puedes usar logs para esta tarea

Comment: ¿a dónde se dirige entonces? ¿las vistas 404 y 503 se muestran correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

Como habrás visto en el método que estás sobreescribiendo,  `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::render`, en él se "rutea" la excepción acorde a sus atributos. Hay muchos casos en donde tu idea funciona, dado que lo indispensable es poder identificar el statusCode de una excepción. En los casos que no, estás invocando al método `getStatusCode` sin tener en cuenta la contravarianza. El método acepta `Throwable` de cualquier tipo, no necesariamente del subtipo que tiene statusCode.

Veamos los casos favorables:

Si la excepción implementa la interfaz `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface` entonces tiene un accesor directo al statusCode

```
 $httpException->getStatusCode();
```

Si una excepción es de tipo `Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException` entonces tiene una propiedad `response` con el accesor `getResponse`. Por transitividad, tiene un statusCode:

```
 $httpResponseException->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
```

Otros errores específicos de Laravel se pueden mapear a excepciones de la familia HttpException de Symfony de manera directa:

- ModelNotFoundException -> NotFoundHttpException
- RecordNotFoundException -> NotFoundHttpException
- AuthorizationException -> AccessDeniedHttpException

(de todos modos éstos son casos particulares de `HttpExceptionInterface` así que están cubiertos por la primera condición)

Hay otros casos en donde la excepción  implementa la interfaz `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable`,  que no *tiene* específicamente una respuesta o un statusCode pero puede *convertirse* (coercionarse) a una  respuesta con el método `toResponse`. Por transitividad, tiene un statusCode.

```
 $responsable->toResponse()->getStatusCode()
```

Finalmente hay casos particulares en donde la excepción por sí misma no te puede decir su statuscode pero la lógica de dominio sabe que (por ejemplo) una excepción  `AuthenticationException` arrojada por un middleware y sus guards equivaldría a un status code 401 *si acaso fuera pertinente expresarla como respuesta* (que no siempre es así).

Para todo el resto de las docenas de excepciones posibles no hay una equivalencia con un determinado statusCode. A grandes rasgos:

```
public function obtenerStatusCode(\Throwable $e) {
 
   if($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface) {
       return $e->getStatusCode();
   }

   if($e instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException) {
       return $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
   }

   if($e instanceof \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable) {
       return $e->toResponse()->getStatusCode();
   }

   if($e instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException) {
       return 401;
   }

   // y si entras aquí es porque te toca definir qué se hace con otros casos

 }
```

Con respecto a tu pregunta

> ¿a dónde se dirige entonces? ¿las vistas 404 y 503 se muestran correctamente?

Tú tienes definido que si el statusCode es 404 se dibuje esa vista. Significa que la excepción es (posiblemente) del tipo `NotFoundHttpException` de Symfony, que a su vez puede haberse arrojado como consecuencia de excepciones de Laravel como `ModelNotFoundException` o  `RelationNotFoundException` o simplemente una ruta inexistente.

De la misma manera, tienes definida la vista para las excepciones cuyo statusCode es 503, o sea viene del tipo  `ServiceUnavailableHttpException` de Symfony que a su vez puede venir del tipo `MaintenanceModeException` de Laravel.

De todos los mentados tipos, **no hay ninguno cuyo statusCode puedas obtener directamente que te vaya a devolver 500**, porque el error 500 es el fallback para todas las excepciones que no tiene objeto clasificar o simplemente no capturaste correctamente.

Como desde ya sabes que lo que te llega es de tipo `ErrorException`, lo más probable es que venga de `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError` y puede originarse de cualquier error de PHP. Lo más sano es que manejes esa condición definiendo:

```
   if($e instanceof \ErrorException) {
       return 500;
   }
```

Si es que eso tiene sentido en tu flujo.

#### Edit: Otro punto de vista

La respuesta se basa en tu pregunta, en lo que quieres obtener y espero más te sirva.

Sin embargo hay otra escuela de pensamiento que me hace mucho sentido, respecto a los headers:

```
 - headers 200 y 300: todo bien
 - headers 4xx : es tu culpa
 - headers 5xx : es nuestra culpa
```

En el sentido que la familia de statusCode 4xx indica un error del usuario, por ejemplo cuando pide una ruta que no existe o manda a persistir una entidad con un ID incompatible, o cuando pide una ruta sin estar autenticado. Es su culpa.

Un error 404 cuando pide una entidad en una ruta correcta pero el modelo no existe es en realidad un error engañoso. El usuario no ha cometido ningún error.

De todos modos si lo importante es mostrarle un mensaje con feedback es mejor apelar al 404 que nada.

Answer (score 1):

Las [vistas de error personalizadas (hasta laravel 5.6)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#custom-http-error-pages) se crean añadiendo la carpeta "errors" en "resources/views/" y para cada error que se quiera personalizar un *template **Blade*** nombrado con cada código de error. Así, si se quiere crear una página de error 404 personalizada, se crea el fichero:

```
"resources/views/errors/404.blade.php"
```

Desde este momento los errores 404 en la aplicación cargarán este *template* y mostrarán su contenido.

Los errores que no tengan un *template* definido, seguirán mostrando las páginas de error que trae ***Laravel*** por defecto.

> Nota:
> desde Laravel 5.7, esta disponible la opción de "publicar" todas las vistas
> de error que trae Laravel para poder editarlas, con el comando:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

Este comando, genera el mismo directorio: "resources/views/errors/" de forma automática con el siguiente contenido:

```
401.blade.php
403.blade.php
404.blade.php
419.blade.php
429.blade.php
500.blade.php
503.blade.php
illustrated-layout.blade.php
layout.blade.php
minimal.blade.php
```

*Si cuando lanzamos el comando de publicación de vistas este directorio ya existía y teníamos algunas vistas, estas no serán sobreescritas.*

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes las vistas en la carpeta errors, entonces usa el método **abort()**:

```
if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 500) {
    abort(500);
}
if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
    abort(404);
}
if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 503) {
    abort(503);
}
```

Ahora si deseas mostrar una vista de error de acuerdo a una instancia de la excepción puede hacerlo así:

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
    abort(404);
}

if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
    abort(405);
}
```